# How do i get multiple edittext values from dynamically added views in a linearlayout inside listview

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement a list of edittext inside a listview. I have successfully added that by adding dynamically view inside a vertical linearlayout. Now i need to get the values from every edittext values from each main list item. Please check the image below

[image file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AawT.png)

Below is the code i am using to add dynamic edittext to the vertical linearlayout

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView != null){
        return convertView;
    }

    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);

    final LinearLayout subItem = convertView.findViewById(R.id.lvSubItem);
    subItem.removeAllViews();

    for (final Faltu faltu : posms.get(position).getFaltus()){
        View subView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.subitem,null);
        final EditText subEditText = subView.findViewById(R.id.subItem);

        subItem.addView(subView);
        subEditText.setTag(subItem.indexOfChild(subView));


    return convertView;
}
```

I have tried with adding textChangedListener to the editext inside the for loop and onTextChanged i haved updated my value list with the text. But unfortunately it updates all values with same value.

```
subEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                subEditText.requestFocus();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (s.length() > 0){
                    posms.get(position).getFaltus().get((Integer) subEditText.getTag()).setNumber(s.toString());

                }
            }
        });
```

Any suggestion is appreciaed

Answer (score 0):

Try using these lines of code

```
for (int i = 0; i < posms.get(position).getFaltus().size(); i++) {

            final Faltu faltu = posms.get(position).getFaltus().get(i);

            View subView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.subitem, null);
            final EditText subEditText = subView.findViewById(R.id.subItem);

            subItem.addView(subView);
            subEditText.setTag(i);

            subEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                    subEditText.requestFocus();
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if (s.length() > 0){
                        //posms.get(position).getFaltus().get(i).setNumber(s.toString());
                        faltu.setNumber(s.toString());
                    }
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: does     faltu.setNumber(s.toString()); updates the value also in the list?

Comment: yes but you have to notify the adapter by calling `notifyDataSetChanged`

Comment: any idea where should i call notifyDataSetChanged ?

Comment: @user3921178  just tried your code. Unfortunately it updates all the items with same values.

Comment: if you do any change in list then after change you have to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to display effect of changed list in listview. Wherever you applied changes in list, call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.  In your case it should be in `afterTextChanged` after `faltu` object updated. Note :- The listview updates after every text input in edittext so it may be stuck.

Comment: i just tried that, but unfortunately it updates all the items with same value.